# UItableview DeleteRow with animation in transparent table look ugly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I use this code to do animation in insert or delete

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Since it remove a cell from tableview, it tries to hide it behind the cell above.
Because it is transparent cell the animation looks very ugly.

Please help!!!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here, this code comes with a template file for using the UITableViewController

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source.
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}   
}
```

That should help you out a lot! Hope this helps